# Pandas: How to drop leading missing values for all columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

With a pandas dataframe of the form:

```
     A     B     C
ID                
1   10   NaN   NaN
2   20   NaN   NaN
3   28  10.0   NaN
4   32  18.0  10.0
5   34  22.0  16.0
6   34  24.0  20.0
7   34  26.0  21.0
8   34  26.0  22.0
```

How can I remove a varying number of initial missing values? Initially, I'd like to forward fill the last values of the "new" columns so I'll end up with this:

```
    A     B     C
0  10  10.0  10.0
1  20  18.0  16.0
2  28  22.0  20.0
3  32  24.0  21.0
4  34  26.0  22.0
5  34  26.0  22.0
6  34  26.0  22.0
7  34  26.0  22.0
```

But I guess it would be just as natural to have nans on the remaining rows too:

```
    A     B     C
0  10  10.0  10.0
1  20  18.0  16.0
2  28  22.0  20.0
3  32  24.0  21.0
4  34  26.0  22.0
5  34  26.0   NaN
6  34   NaN   NaN
7  34   NaN   NaN
```

Here's a visual representation of the issue:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image: frea]

I've come up with a cumbersome approach using a for loop where I remove the leading nans using `df.dropna()`, count the number of values I've removed (N), append the last available number N times, and build a new dataframe column by column. But this turned out to be pretty slow for larger dataframes. I feel like this is something that's already a built-in functionality of the omnipotent pandas library, but I haven't found anything so far. Does anyone have a suggestion to a less cumbersome way of doing this?

**Complete code with a sample dataset:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                    'A': [10,20,28,32,34,34,34,34],
                   'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 10,18,22,24,26,26],
                    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,10,16,20,21,22]})
df=df.set_index('ID')

# container for dataframe
# to be built using a for loop
df_new=pd.DataFrame()

for col in df.columns:
    # drop missing values column by column
    ser = df[col]
    original_length = len(ser)
    ser_new = ser.dropna()

    # if leading values are removed for N rows.
    # append last value N times for the last rows
    if len(ser_new) <= original_length:
        N = original_length - len(ser_new)
        ser_append = [ser.iloc[-1]]*N
        #ser_append = [np.nan]*N
        ser_new = ser_new.append(pd.Series(ser_append), ignore_index=True)
    df_new[col]=ser_new

df_new
```

Comment: are your null values always at the top ? what happens if there is a null value at the bottom of a series?

Comment: @Datanovice In my real world data, yes they're always at the top. At least when reaching the step in the data process described here. I'm handling all other missing values with a forward fill.

Comment: got it, please see solution, there's probably a method to do this without a loop, but I think some form of apply will always be necessary as your doing column wise operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure Pandas solution. Use apply to shift the values up depending on number of leading NaN's and use ffill,

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.isna().sum())).ffill()


    A      B       C
1   10  10.0    10.0
2   20  18.0    16.0
3   28  22.0    20.0
4   32  24.0    21.0
5   34  26.0    22.0
6   34  26.0    22.0
7   34  26.0    22.0
8   34  26.0    22.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that could be possible in one line...

Comment: Pandas is quite amazing :)

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of `shift` and move each series by the number of missing values

```
d = df.isna().sum(axis=0).to_dict() # calculate the number of missing rows per column 

for k,v in d.items():
    df[k] = df[k].shift(-v).ffill()
```

--

```
print(df)

   ID   A     B     C
0   1  10  10.0  10.0
1   2  20  18.0  16.0
2   3  28  22.0  20.0
3   4  32  24.0  21.0
4   5  34  26.0  22.0
5   6  34  26.0  22.0
6   7  34  26.0  22.0
7   8  34  26.0  22.0
```

Comment: Simply awesome!

Comment: Absolutely! In fatct that's probably the very definition of the absolutely least I could do.